# PHP: prevent from encoding é to?

Tags: php, html-entities

I'm importing data from a CSV file to a database. In the CSV file there are a lots of strange characters like (é, ë, ...) that need to be converted to &eacute, &euml to store in the database. Right now all strange characters are converted to a questionmark. But what function do I use to convert them. HTML_ENTITIES, utf8_decode, ...?

I'm using UTF8

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars()` function of PHP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231635/character-encoding-problems-with-reading-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... it *would* be `htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');`. But the approach is wrong.

Checklist:

1. The data of your file is UTF-8
2. When you use string functions with constant strings (e.g. `str_replace('e', 'é', $foo)`) this file is UTF-8
3. The database connection you use allows the transportation of UTF-8 encoded characters and is configured for that (`SET NAMES 'utf8'` for MySQL)
4. The `Content-Type` header (or meta-tag) of your page tells the browser to expect UTF-8